# Sorting the Gridview table using C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013

Currently, I need to sort one of the columns in my Gridview table. The data in the gridview table are retrieved from the SharePoint list instead of retrieved from the SQL database.

I have no idea whats wrong with my code and the column seems like no response after clicking the column title for sorting it.

Can anyone help on this issue? =(

Below is my code for sorting the "Request ID" column.

```html
<tr>
    <td class="grid-td">
        <asp:GridView ID="gridSubmittedRequests" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Both" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" OnPageIndexChanging="gridSubmittedRequests_PageIndexChanging"  OnSorting="gridView_Sorting" PageSize="10" CssClass="grid-format">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Request ID" DataField="ID" SortExpression="ID" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Title" DataField="Title" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Status" DataField="clRequestStatus" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Reason for Rejection" DataField="clReasonForRejection" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Comments" DataField="clApproverComments" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date Created" DataField="Created" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
                <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="clGeneralFormViewLink" HeaderText="Request Link" Text="View Request" />
            </Columns>
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#0072c6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0072c6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:Label ID="lblSubmittedRequestNoRecords" runat="server" Visible="false" CssClass="err-msg"></asp:Label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

```html
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;

using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;

using CL.SPEngine;
using CL.Common.Data;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow;

namespace CL.MDM.WebParts
{
    public partial class RequestorDashboardUserControl : UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
            {
                this.BindGrid();
            }
        }

        private void BindGrid()
        {
            try
            {
                string currentUserMail = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Email;

                #region Draft request query and data binding

                string draftQuery = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='FALSE'/></OrderBy><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author'/><Value Type='Integer'><UserID Type='Integer'/></Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='" + FieldNames.IsDraft + "'/><Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value></Eq></And></Where>";
                string draftViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='" + FieldNames.Title + "' /><FieldRef Name='" + FieldNames.Created + "' /><FieldRef Name='" + FieldNames.RequestLink + "' /><FieldRef Name='" + FieldNames.ID + "' /><FieldRef Name='" + FieldNames.GeneralFormViewLink + "' />";

                DataTable dtMyDraftRequests = this.GetRequestData(draftQuery, draftViewFields);
                if (dtMyDraftRequests != null)
                {
                    this.BindDraftGrid(dtMyDraftRequests);
                }
                else
                {
                    lblDraftRequestNoRecords.Visible = true;
                    lblDraftRequestNoRecords.Text = "No draft requests found";
                }

                #endregion

                #region Submitted request query and data binding

                string submittedQuery = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='FALSE'/></OrderBy><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author'/><Value Type='Integer'><UserID Type='Integer'/></Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='" + FieldNames.IsDraft + "'/><Value Type='Boolean'>0</Value></Eq></And></Where>";
                string submittedViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='" + FieldNames.Title + "' /><FieldRef Name='" + FieldNames.RequestStatus + "' /><FieldRef Name='" + FieldNames.Created + "' /><FieldRef Name='" + FieldNames.RequestLink + "' /><FieldRef Name='" + FieldNames.ID + "' /><FieldRef Name='" + FieldNames.GeneralFormViewLink + "' /><FieldRef Name='" + FieldNames.ReasonForRejection + "' /><FieldRef Name='" + FieldNames.ApproverComments + "' />";

                DataTable dtMySubmittedRequests = this.GetRequestData(submittedQuery, submittedViewFields);
                if (dtMySubmittedRequests != null)
                {
                    this.BindSubmittedGrid(dtMySubmittedRequests);
                }
                else
                {
                    lblSubmittedRequestNoRecords.Visible = true;
                    lblSubmittedRequestNoRecords.Text = "No submitted requests found";
                }

                #endregion
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MDMLogger.Log(TraceSeverity.Unexpected, EventSeverity.Error, "CL.MDM RequestorDashboard BindGrid : Error " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This function is used to get data from Master data requests list. It will accept query and view fields as parameters
        /// It will convert collection of list items to data table.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="query">CAML query in string format to retrieve data from list</param>
        /// <param name="viewFields">View fields to retrieve from the list</param>
        /// <returns>Data table of retrieved items</returns>
        private DataTable GetRequestData(string query, string viewFields)
        {
            DataTable dtMyRequests = null;
            try
            {
                //Getting Master Data Requests list
                SPList mdrList = SPExtension.TryGetListByUrl(SPContext.Current.Web.Lists, Lists.MasterDataRequestForm);
                if (mdrList != null)
                {
                    //Querying list to get required data
                    SPQuery myRequestQuery = new SPQuery();
                    myRequestQuery.Query = query;
                    myRequestQuery.ViewFields = viewFields;

                    //Getting items and converting those items to Data Table
                    SPListItemCollection myRequests = mdrList.GetItems(myRequestQuery);
                    dtMyRequests = new DataTable();
                    dtMyRequests = myRequests.GetDataTable();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MDMLogger.Log(TraceSeverity.Unexpected, EventSeverity.Error, "CL.MDM RequestorDashboard GetRequestData : Error " + ex.Message);
            }

            return dtMyRequests;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This function will bind draft request grid
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dtSource">Data source for grid</param>
        private void BindDraftGrid(DataTable dtSource)
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable dtFinal = AddEditColumn(dtSource);
                gridDraftRequests.DataSource = dtFinal;
                gridDraftRequests.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MDMLogger.Log(TraceSeverity.Unexpected, EventSeverity.Error, "CL.MDM RequestorDashboard BindDraftGrid : Error " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This function will bind submitted request grid
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dtSource">Data source for grid</param>
        private void BindSubmittedGrid(DataTable dtSource)
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable dtSubmittedRequests = GetWrokflowStatus(dtSource);
                gridSubmittedRequests.DataSource = dtSubmittedRequests;
                gridSubmittedRequests.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MDMLogger.Log(TraceSeverity.Unexpected, EventSeverity.Error, "CL.MDM RequestorDashboard BindSubmittedGrid : Error " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private string GetSortDirection(string column)
        {

            // By default, set the sort direction to descending.
            string sortDirection = "DESC";

            // Retrieve the last column that was sorted.
            string sortExpression = ViewState["SortExpression"] as string;

            if (sortExpression != null)
            {
                // Check if the same column is being sorted.
                // Otherwise, the default value can be returned.
                if (sortExpression == column)
                {
                    string lastDirection = ViewState["SortDirection"] as string;
                    if ((lastDirection != null) && (lastDirection == "DESC"))
                    {
                        sortDirection = "ASC";
                    }
                }
            }

            // Save new values in ViewState.
            ViewState["SortDirection"] = sortDirection;
            ViewState["SortExpression"] = column;

            return sortDirection;
        }

        protected void gridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = gridSubmittedRequests.DataSource as DataTable;

            if (dataTable != null)
            {
                DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
                //dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirectionToSql(e.SortDirection);
                dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);

                gridSubmittedRequests.DataSource = dataView;
                gridSubmittedRequests.DataBind();
            }

        } 

        protected void gridSubmittedRequests_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            gridSubmittedRequests.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            this.BindGrid();
        }

        protected void gridDraftRequests_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            gridDraftRequests.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            this.BindGrid();
        }

        private DataTable AddEditColumn(DataTable dtSource)
        {
            dtSource.Columns.Add(GeneralConstants.EditLinkColumn);
            for (int counter = 0; counter < dtSource.Rows.Count; counter++)
            {
                string editLink = string.Format(GeneralConstants.GeneralFormEditLinkUrl, SPContext.Current.Web.Url.TrimEnd('/'), Convert.ToString(dtSource.Rows[counter][FieldNames.ID]));
                dtSource.Rows[counter][GeneralConstants.EditLinkColumn] = editLink;
            }
            return dtSource;
        }

        private DataTable GetWrokflowStatus(DataTable dtSource)
        {
            SPList mdmList = SPExtension.TryGetListByUrl(SPContext.Current.Web.Lists, Lists.MasterDataRequestForm);
            if (mdmList != null)
            {
                for (int counter = 0; counter < dtSource.Rows.Count; counter++)
                {
                    string itemID = Convert.ToString(dtSource.Rows[counter][FieldNames.ID]);
                    SPListItem mdmItem = mdmList.GetItemById(Convert.ToInt32(itemID));

                    if (SPContext.Current.Site.WorkflowManager.GetItemWorkflows(mdmItem).Count > 0)
                    {
                        SPWorkflow workflow = SPContext.Current.Site.WorkflowManager.GetItemWorkflows(mdmItem)[0];
                        if (workflow.ParentAssociation.Name.Contains(GeneralConstants.WorkflowName))
                        {
                            if (workflow.InternalState.ToString().Contains(SPWorkflowState.Terminated.ToString()))
                            {
                                dtSource.Rows[counter][FieldNames.RequestStatus] = "Error occured / Workflow Terminated";
                            }
                            else if (workflow.InternalState.ToString().Contains(SPWorkflowState.Faulting.ToString()))
                            {
                                dtSource.Rows[counter][FieldNames.RequestStatus] = "Error occured / Workflow Error";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return dtSource;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to write minimal and completely verifiable code, so that it is easier for the reader to go through your code too, its currently very long.

Comment: You said you want to sort RequestID but in a CAML you are sorting it from the Created, why? If you want to get the Sorted by Request ID you can put ID in sorting field so that it will give your desired Output. you can user CAMLQUERYBuilder tool for the same.